# Setting timeshift backup to harddrive, getting "Device not found" error

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ext4, timeshift

I'm trying to set the backup location for timeshift to a new external hard drive I just bought.
I formatted the drive w/ an ext4 filesystem w/ the command:

```
    sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sde
```

I then ran the commands:

```
    sudo mkdir /mnt/backup_hd
    sudo mount /dev/sde /mnt/backup_hd
```

Then I try to set the timeshift backup location with the command:

```
    sudo timeshift --snapshot-device /mnt/backup_hd
```

And I get the error:

```
    App config loaded: /etc/timeshift/timeshift.json
    E: Device not found: '/mnt/backup_hd'
    App config saved: /etc/timeshift/timeshift.json
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read the messages for the command you gave, at the `sudo mount /dev/sde /mnt/backup_hd` I'd have expected error message(s) in that you tried to `mount` a device (*not a partition*). Your `mkfs.ext4` command will according to the manual "*mke2fs is used to create an ext2, ext3, or ext4 file system, usually in a disk partition (or file) named by device*"  ie. it created a *fs* on a partition, but you tried to mount the device itself; not what you created. You've not provided any OS/release details; so your system may differ to what I'd expect on my OS/release.

Comment: The timeshift documentation isn't clear, but it looks like the `--snapshot` option expects a *block device* argument, rather than a mountpoint. What happens if you unmount it (`sudo umount /dev/sde`), then try `sudo timeshift --snapshot-device /dev/sde`?

Comment: So confused.  Based on guiverc's comment, I figured I had made a mistake in formatting using '/dev/sde'.  So I ran commands to recreate the partition 'sde1' w/in the 'sde' device.   And then mounted 'sde1' as before and re-ran the timeshift commands but got the same error.

Comment: But then tried what steeldrive suggested and typed:  sudo umount /dev/sde   and then ran the command: sudo timeshift --snapshot-device /dev/sde  And then did not receive the ' Device not found' error.  But with 'sde' not mounted.  How can this backup work?  I'm clearly not understanding the fundamentals of mounting and how to get timeshift to talk to devices/partitions.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

@steeldriver had pretty much the right answer.  However, it was not necessary for the device to be unmounted.  It was just necessary for me to specify a *device* in the timeshift --snapshot-device command and not a *partition*.  So even with /dev/sde1 mounted, I just had to run:

```
sudo timeshift --snapshot-device /dev/sde
```

Then, upon creating my first timeshift backup, the software just creates a folder at the top of the partition named 'timeshift' and stores all backups within.  Thanks for the help.